# How to set react native TextInput to be read by screen readers as cellphone number input

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to add accessibility to my `TextInput` in react native to be read as cellphone number instead of a number, like the following.

```
<TextInput
    style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
    editable={false}
    accessibilityLabel={'26726855243'}
    value={'26726855243'}
  />
```

This is being read as number by android TalkBack and iOS VoiceOver.
I have tried adding spaces between the numbers but still didn't work, `accessibilityLabel={'26726855243'.split('').join(' ')}`

Comment: Did you get an answer for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSS3 Speech Module provides support for this behavior: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-speech/

For your specific example, you could create a "phone" class as follows:

```css
<style>
  .phone {speak: digits;}
</style>
```

Note that this behavior is currently only supported by VoiceOver, not by TalkBack.

For Talkback and most other screen readers, inserting commas rather than spaces will work (screen readers generally pause for commas, periods, semi-colons, exclamation marks and question marks, but not spaces):

```js
accessibilityLabel={'26726855243'.split('').join(',')}
```

However! I would encourage you to consider *not* trying to manage screen reader behavior in this way. Bear in mind that modern screen readers have a variety of *user* settings for handling number and acronym pronunciation. By trying to manage their pronunciation to this level on the developer side you may cause unexpected behavior for users.

Comment: Does this work in React Native? I believe the OP was asking in React Native...

Comment: This doesn't work for me at all, the CSS3 isn't valid for React Native styles and talkback ignores the  `accessibilityLabel` when the TextInput has a value (using in built React Native `TextInput`)